# How to run a custom System.Attribute over an ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, ashx

Normally, on a usual `aspx` file, I can use `System.Attribute` at the begining of the page, like:

```
    [AuthorizePage()]
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    public class AuthorizePage : System.Attribute
    {
         public AuthorizePage()
         {
            //do some stuff to authorize
         }
    }
```

And before the page initializes the Attribute's constructor runs and do some stuff to ensure a person is currently logged in, otherwise the attribute constructor Redirects user to a login page.

I wanted to do the same on a `HttpHandler` (`ashx` file), but the attribute **never** initializes when on a ashx page.

```
[AuthorizePage()]
public class AjaxHandler : MuCustomClassBase, IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
     //The interface implementations and some other custom private methods
}
```

I do an AJAX Call to this `ashx` page. Could this be the reason why the Attribute doesn't run? Or any other things I must know?

Eventually, I would be extremely happy to know How to run a Custom System.Attribute over an ashx file?

Comment: You're trying to re-invent ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all yes you are reinventing the ActionFilterAttribute in Asp.Net MVC. But, I have to ask if you really need to use attribute? I suggest you to use inheritance model. Let me simply explain; you might have a SecurePage : Page class that implements the security operations. You may then pass the security code that is related to the derived page.

And if you insist on using attributes, you should intersect the handler mechanism by writing a base factory handler that routes to the needed handler. This handler should behave like a mediator object.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using ASP.Net authentication, you can just add the .ashx to the list of protected pages in web.config and IIS/ASP.Net will take care of the rest:

```
  <location path="AjaxRequests.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

If you are using a self-built authentication scheme, you could override `OnProcessRequest` and  perform the necessary authentication in that method, redirecting as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, it appears I forgot to mention that. I use my own authentication system. But again, thank you for the input.

Comment: I figured that might be the case; in this case, I suggest that you add the authentication code to OnProcessRequest. If you have multiple ashx pages, you could make a base class that they inherit from that always performs the authentication (this is how we have our apps structured).

Answer (score 2):

Attributes don't do anything by themselves. You can pile 10 random attributes on a class and nothing will really happen. Attributes just provide metadata about the class/method/property.

There should be a piece of code that looks at the metadata and act on it. Since you seem to be using custom `AuthorizePageAttribute` such piece of code either don't run for handlers or does not expect class that is not derived from Page to have such attribute.

To fix an issue you need to find what handles you custom attribute and fix it. You may need to add similar code to your handlers directly.

The fact that your code in constructor of attribute does something useful for a page class on every request to that page sounds suspicious - I'd expect such attributes to be created once per type instance. Relying on non-trivial code in constructor of an attribute to run per-instance of the class seems dangerous to my.